# Could not generate extensions' documentation when creating custom controller service in NIFI

Tags: java, apache-nifi

I tried to create a custom controller service by using [this guide](https://medium.com/hashmapinc/creating-custom-processors-and-controllers-in-apache-nifi-e14148740ea). It is worked perfectly in nifi 1.9.2 version. But when I try with NIFI 1.11.3 version, I'm getting the following issue. I googled it, But couldn't find a way to fix that. Could someone please help me?

```
[INFO] Found a dependency on version 1.11.3 of NiFi API
[ERROR] Could not generate extensions' documentation
org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to create Extension Documentation
    at org.apache.nifi.NarMojo.generateDocumentation (NarMojo.java:596)
    at org.apache.nifi.NarMojo.execute (NarMojo.java:499)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.nifi.NarMojo.getRequiredServiceDefinitions (NarMojo.java:708)
    at org.apache.nifi.NarMojo.writeDocumentation (NarMojo.java:634)
    at org.apache.nifi.NarMojo.writeDocumentation (NarMojo.java:605)
    at org.apache.nifi.NarMojo.generateDocumentation (NarMojo.java:577)
    at org.apache.nifi.NarMojo.execute (NarMojo.java:499)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo (DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:137)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:210)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute (LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:305)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute (DefaultMaven.java:192)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute (DefaultMaven.java:105)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute (MavenCli.java:956)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain (MavenCli.java:288)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main (MavenCli.java:192)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0 (Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke (DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java:498)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced (Launcher.java:282)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch (Launcher.java:225)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode (Launcher.java:406)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:347)
    at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main (Launcher.java:47)
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
    <artifactId>nifi-standard-services-api-nar</artifactId>
    <version>1.11.3</version>
    <type>nar</type>
</dependency>
```

You might be missing this in your pom.xml

Answer (score 7):

`org.apache.nifi:nifi-standard-services-api-nar`
dependency needs to be added in `pom.xml` of `nifi-*-nar` module.

Comment: hm, i have it there but still get ````org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Failed to create Extension Documentation```` for nifi 1.13.2. What else could be the problem?

Answer (score 0):

this is worked and i am converting my controller services to 1.16.3 version and the same exact issue i got it so i have added this dependency.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.nifi</groupId>
        <artifactId>nifi-standard-services-api-nar</artifactId>
        <version>1.16.3</version>
        <type>nar</type>
    </dependency>
```